# PSD to Bootstrap or HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have just started learning **BootStrap** , i was wondering that if i should convert my **PSD** to **HTML/CSS** first and then to bootstrap or directly to Bootstrap.

Comment: can u explain a lil more

Comment: BootStrap css classes are not recognized by Photoshop. So, Photoshop can not compile your psd file.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is if you want to get going with setting up a website, please consider Adobe Muse.  I don't work for Adobe but it's a really nice program.  It allows you to layout a full-blown website with your Photoshop graphics cut up the way they need to be cut up, then imported into Muse.

I think it's very reasonably priced as well.  I hope this helps.